# AJAX call with jqPlot not showing axis correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have an AJAX function which calls a list of records from a database. I am then attempting to use jqPlot to show certain rows on the table with the x-axis being the timestampt of a record and the y-axis being heart-rate (hr).

The call to the jqPlot function is made in the successs of the AJAX call as follows:

```
success: function(data) {
                if(data.moves) {
                    $('#records').html('');
                    var html = "";
                    var dataarray = [];
                    html += "<table>";
                    $.each(data.moves, function(k, v) { 
                        dataarray.push([v.timestamp, v.hr]);
                        html += "<tr>";
                        html += "<td>" + v.hr + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + v.time + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + v.title + "</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + v.zone + "</td>";
                        html += "</tr>";
                    });
                    html += "</table>";
                    $('.records').html(html);   
                    var plot1 = $.jqplot('records',  [dataarray], {
                        title: 'Heart Rate for this move',
                        axesDefaults: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 200
                        },
                        axes: {
                            xaxis: {
                                label: "Time",
                                pad: 0,
                                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                                tickOptions: {
                                    formatString: '%H:%M',
                                    angle: -45
                                }
                            },
                            yaxis: {
                                label: "Heart Rate"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

As you can see I am looping through each record that is returned in the data variable and populating an array called 'dataarray' with the 'hr (heart-rate)' and 'time (datestamp)' fields to be used by jqPlot.

Here is the json array returned back from the AJAX call:

```
$moves = $this->myzone_model->getUsersMoves($options);
            $moves_arr = array();
            foreach($moves as $move) {
                $timestamp = strtotime($move['time']);
                $moves_arr[] = array(
                    'myzone_user_hr_records_id' => $move['myzone_user_hr_records_id'],
                    'GUID'                      => $move['GUID'],
                    'hr'                        => $move['hr'],
                    'time'                      => $move['time'],
                    'timestamp'                 => $timestamp,
                    'title'                     => $move['title'],
                    'maxHR'                     => $move['maxHR'],
                    'zone'                      => $move['zone']
                );
            }
            $json = array('moves' => $moves_arr);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working and I ma not sure why. This is what I get:

[image]

As you can see the plots aren't appearing and the x-axis is not displaying the correct range of times.
I havn't really used jqPlot before so can't seem to debug this one. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: A couple of questions: 1-have you tested this with sample data, 2-have you got some real JSON data from your query i.e. what is in `[dataarray]`?

Comment: Hi, I have tried with sample data and I get an issue where the time repeats itself on every tick. Here is an example of the data in dataarray = [[1353438096, "64"], [1353438106,"66"], [1353438116, "71"], [1353438492, "60"], [1353438502, "66"]]

Comment: After experimenting on jfiddle I have noticed that it is an issue with three trailing zeros missing from the end of my timestamps. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have managed to get this sorted thanks to some suggestions of checking the output of the dataarray array.
Basically as UNIX timestamps work in seconds and Javascript timestamp in milliseconds I needed to convert my timestamps from a UNIX timestampt to Javascript in order for the dates to be read correctly. 
Hope this helps someone else!